# AMQ6004S: An error occurred during IBM MQ initialization or ending. exitvalue = 71

Tags: ibm-mq, azure-files

I have created Queue manager on azure file share and when I am starting I getting below error.
I have given all the permission to file share folder.

If specific rights needs to be given to any user or group.

after analyzing log found below content.

```
11/3/2020 06:14:24 - Process(5044.1) User(wmqvm1) Program(STRMQM.EXE)
                      Host(wmqvm1) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0)
                      Time(2020-11-03T06:14:24.128Z)
                      CommentInsert1(Windows Server 2019 Server Datacenter Edition, Build 17763 (MQ Windows (x64 platform) 64-bit))
                      CommentInsert2(C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1))
                      CommentInsert3(9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL))
                     
AMQ6287I: IBM MQ V9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL).

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ system information: 
Host Info         :- Windows Server 2019 Server Datacenter Edition, Build 17763
(MQ Windows (x64 platform) 64-bit) 
Installation      :- C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1) 
Version           :- 9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL)
ACTION:
None. 
----- amqxeida.c : 6604 -------------------------------------------------------
11/3/2020 06:14:24 - Process(5044.1) User(wmqvm1) Program(STRMQM.EXE)
                      Host(wmqvm1) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0)
                      Time(2020-11-03T06:14:24.127Z)
                      ArithInsert1(85)
                     
AMQ7125I: There are 85 days left in the trial period for this copy of IBM MQ.

EXPLANATION:
This copy of IBM MQ is licensed for a limited period only.
ACTION:
None. 
----- amqxlic0.c : 613 --------------------------------------------------------
```

```
C:\Users\wmqvm1>dspmqver
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200710.TRIAL
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for Windows (x64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Windows Server 2019 Server Datacenter Edition, Build 17763
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ
DataPath:    C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ
MaxCmdLevel: 920
LicenseType: Trial
```

Comment: What do you see in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG fine?  Are any FDCs produced?  Is below error supposed to refer to the question title?

Comment: According to IBM Knowledge Center, exitvalue = 71 is an Unexpected Error, so I do hope there is something in an FDC or the error log, to allow further investigation.

Comment: @JoshMc yes error is as title sorry for typo.

Comment: @MoragHughson I haven't found any log yet if you can help me with that?

Comment: @JoshMc log file not generated and not sure about FDC.

Comment: @JoshMc No other errors or logs generated. may be is it like trail version issues?

Comment: @JoshMc the errors I have shown is from the same file you mentioned. Log files for qmgrs/log/<queuemanager_name> are not generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224020/discussion-between-niket-and-joshmc).

Comment: Can you confirm you have checked both `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\errors` and `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\<queue_manager_name>\errors`?

Comment: Yes I checked both places

Comment: Hi Niket, you could attempt a early trace `strmqtrc -e -t detail -t all` to start it, then reproduct the issue, then `endmqtrc -a` to end it, then review the `*.TRC` files under `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\trace`, look for the one that indicates it is for `strmqm` and see if you see any cause for the RC=71 error.  Short of this, I think you would need to open a case with IBM, but given that you are using a Trial license you may not have that option.  If you have any IBM sales contacts you could try to go that route to get some further assistance.